# Delete an item on click

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to write the very first to-do application in REACT. I want to add functionality to delete to-do item when the user clicks on the delete icon. When I click on delete icon it only removes the text. Here I would like to delete the entire item. Can someone please suggest?

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import TodoList from './TodoList';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [todos, setTodo] = useState([]);

  const addTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const id = uuidv4();
    setTodo([...todos, { id: id, text: input}]) 
    // setTodo({todos: [...todos, input], id })
    setInput('');
  } 

  const deleteTodo = (id) => {
    console.log("id" + id);
    const filteredItem = todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id);
    setTodo([filteredItem]);
  }

  return ( 
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <input type="text" value={input} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}/>
        <button type="submit" onClick={addTodo}>Enter</button>
      </form>
      <TodoList todos={todos} deletetodo={deleteTodo}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

TodoList.js

```
import React from 'react'
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';

const todo = ({todos, deletetodo}) => {

    return (
        <div>
          {todos.map(todo => (
            <li key={todo.id}> 
              {todo.text}  
              <div> 
                <DeleteIcon onClick={(todo) => deletetodo(todo.id)}/> 
                <EditIcon/> 
              </div>
            </li> 
          ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default todo;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. I will start with the most obvious. You re-render your `App` on EVERY change of the input field. That's just unnecessary. So insated of storing the value of the input in a state variable, I would use [useRef()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). So you only really need one state variable, one that stores the list of todos.

Second, your filter is correct, but then you incorrectly set the state variable with the filtered result:

```
const filteredItem = todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id);
setTodo([filteredItem]);
```

It will already return an array and there is no need to wrap it into another one.

With those 2 main issue fixed, here is a working example along with a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-swirles-b6w8m?file=/src/App.js):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import "./styles.css";

const TodoList = ({ todos, deletetodo }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {todos.map((todo) => (
        <li key={todo.id}>
          {todo.text}
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => deletetodo(todo.id)}>delete</button>
            <button>edit</button>
          </div>
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [todos, setTodo] = useState([]);

  const input = React.useRef();

  const addTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const id = uuidv4();
    setTodo([...todos, { id: id, text: input.current.value }]);
    input.current.value = "";
  };

  const deleteTodo = (id) => {
    setTodo(todos.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <input ref={input} type="text" />
        <button type="submit" onClick={addTodo}>
          Enter
        </button>
      </form>
      <TodoList todos={todos} deletetodo={deleteTodo} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in how you're setting `todo` in `deleteTodo`:

```
const deleteTodo = (id) => {
    console.log("id" + id);
    const filteredItem = todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id);
    // Mistake! Your filteredItem is an array, you're putting your array into an array.
    setTodo([filteredItem]);
  }
```

Consequently, when you pass it further down, your component tries to get `[filteredItem].text`, which is `undefined` and React sees an empty string.

Fix:

```
setTodo(filteredItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues within the code:
First one is setting the values after deleting the row:

should be like this : `setTodo(filteredItem);`

Second issue was calling the onClick function, you already have the id with you so no need to re-call it again:

```
        <div>
          {todos.map(todoss => 
            <li onClick={() => deletetodo(todoss.id)} key={todoss.id}> 
              {todoss.text}
            </li> 
          )}
        </div>
```